# No "Distribution Provisioning Profiles" tab

Tags: iphone

Today under developer.apple.com member center > iOS Provisioning Portal > Provisioning menu
when clicked only brings up the "Development Provisioning Profiles" 
it has to "Distribution Provisioning Profiles" !
Any idea why this is so? Any change in the way we need to create "Distribution Provisioning Profiles"

Comment: Same issue for me. Maybe Apple is changing something...

Answer (score 8):

I had the Same problem. The Solution was that I was Admin for iOS Development, BUT only a member in Safari Development . Tell your agent to make you Admin for safari too and you will be able see the Distribution Tab.

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me and clearly looks like a bug from Apple.

Comment: Same here... it was Mac Development rather than Safari though. Probably same underlying cause.

Comment: Same here. Mac Development.

Answer (score 0):

Only certain users in the portal have permissions to see/use the Distribution Provisioning Profiles tab.  I believe "Team Member" roles are not able to see the Distribution tab.  Make sure the user you are using to login with is a "Team Agent".

Comment: I am the Team Agent, it was there an hour back.. then the site said it is updating and now the tab is missing. Eric, can you please see if you can see the tab? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Sree - Sounds like it was a temporary issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, matter of fact all tabs have disappeared in the Provisioning section (including "Development" and "How to". Last time I was able to access the Distribution tab was last friday. I have not been able to find an explanation on the developer portal. I guess at this point we'll have to wait. I'll be sure to post an answer as soon as the problem gets solved on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me. Yesterday all works fine but today the Distribution Profile Tab disappears. I hope it just a bug on the site!